# Word for a certain kind of mixed emotion

Tags: single-word-requests

I simultaneously regret the way wind turbines alter the landscape but I am thankful for the clean energy they provide.  What word expresses this mix of emotions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ambivalent, Ambivalence

"The clean energy provided by wind turbines comes at a great cost to migrating bird populations, causing me to feel ambivalent about my support."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalence

Comment: You should provide a quote and link to a dictionary definition.

Comment: 50 reputation points are required for me to comment on the *on hold* decision by tchrist above, but I’m allowed to comment here. I am a brand new user, my apologies for my faux pas. I added the "use the word in a sentence" sentence as requested, and used the op subject matter. Could the dictionary definition links suffice or is an example sentence always required? It seems using any word in a sentence which relates to feelings (I.e. ambivalent) could always be construed as "opinion" and not "facts"?